# How do you get Time Crystals (or, how do you sacrifice Alicorns)?

Tags: kittens-game

In Kittens, I need to get Time Crystals for my next technology, Chrono Physics. The Wiki says to get them by sacrificing Alicorns.

Great, I finally have the Alicorns (17 at this time). Checking the Wiki, and checking all the tabs, I do not see an option to sacrifice them. **How do I sacrifice them, and get my special Time Crystals?** I expected them to be under Science or Religion, but I don't see a button there to sacrifice them. Build 1.0.3.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have 25 Alicorns there will be an option in the Religion tab to Sacrifice your Alicorns.

Here is the code

```
dojo.declare("com.nuclearunicorn.game.ui.SacrificeAlicornsBtn", com.nuclearunicorn.game.ui.ButtonModern, {

    onClick: function(){
        this.animate();

        if (this.enabled && this.hasResources()){
            this.payPrice();
            this.sacrifice(1);
        }
    },

    sacrifice: function(amt){
        var amt = amt || 1;
        var alicornsCount = 25 * amt;

        this.game.msg(alicornsCount + " alicorns banished. You've got " + amt + " time crystals!");
        this.game.resPool.get("timeCrystal").value += amt;
    },

    updateVisible: function(){
        this.setVisible(this.game.resPool.get("alicorn").value >= 25);
    }
});
```